# Zoom and Location Buttons position at the map screen

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2

in Google Maps v.2 if I set

```
 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)
```

then I see a "location" button in a upper right conner. But is it possible to specify another position of this button at the map screen? for example left in the middle?
The same for Zoom buttons..

Or any other approach to do this?

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/how-to-change-the-position-of-maps-apis-get-my-location-button