# Google map version2 shows blank space in android?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In my application am using Google map version 2 just run the project it show the map and blank space in the map.Below am attached the screen shot and how to reposition the zoom control button to top right or left corner.I am new to Google map version 2.Can any one know please help met o solve this problem.

**My XML coding**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

**Screen shot**
[image]

Comment: show is some code manifest file xml file.

Comment: @Raghunandan you want manifest file code.

Comment: There is probably some problem with your Maps API key. Did you generate one to your keystore and put it into your Manifest file?

Comment: Am I understanding your screenshot correctly, you are seeing the map in bottom half and the top half of your screen is blank? Also can you show your complete xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your second question `how to reposition the zoom control button to top right or left corner`

[Two options explained in this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/how-to-change-the-position-of-maps-apis-get-my-location-button): 1, Access the view used to display the standard zoom buttons and then adjust its position 2, disable the standard buttons and add your own custom buttons at desired location