# Relocate "My Location" Button in Google Maps v1

Tags: android, google-maps

I know Google Maps v1 is deprecated, but I have to make a small change in an existing app which uses v1. The MapView shows the "My Location" button in the upper right corner. I would like to move the button to the bottom left corner but cannot find anything about changing the location in the documentation. Is there a possibility to change the location of this button?

Edit: I am using Google Maps **V1**, not V2.

Comment: Follow [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/how-to-change-the-position-of-maps-apis-get-my-location-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/how-to-change-the-position-of-maps-apis-get-my-location-button)

Comment: @Kody Your solution is for v2, not v1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing well but according to my understand i give you a layout. use below layout :

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/mapFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<{ your map(v1) with package name and set proprty}
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myMapLocationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    android:text="My Location" />
```

i think it will help.