# Can someone explain to me the magic behind FindViewById(1) or FindViewById(2)?

Tags: android

[UPDATE] -- Just wanted to confirm to everyone that I agree it's ALWAYS a bad idea to use a hard coded number.  My curiousity was when using the Maps API what is the 1, 2 constant value enumerated to.  I would have felt more comfortable if I found something like R.id.my_current_location_view.

I see that code littered in this question and other questions.  How do people know to use findViewById(1) etc? vs. findViewById(R.id.something);

[Change position of Google Maps API's "My location" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/how-to-change-the-position-of-maps-apis-get-my-location-button)

There seems to be some deep confusion in this question.  I am wondering what the magic numbers findViewById(1) is.. If you click on the link you will see that no one has supplied the setId(1) value to the mapView but somehow people know to check the parent View and then findViewById(1) and findViewById(2)..

I asked the question there as well so the context wouldn't be lost but it seems no one can explain this.

Comment: so apparently it is a magic number.  The ID is from the hierarchyviewer.  and if google decides to change their id in google play services then people who have this code in there will have to change it as well but i've seen this so many places..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an overall bad idea to use this approach with hard coded ids especially if you are not the one who set them as they are subject to change.

However, to answer the question to figure out the id to use, one option is to do a lot of guess and check work using the Android Studio debugger to manually traverse the view hierarchy. That would likely take a lot of time so a much easier approach is to just use the [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) which is available in both Android Studio and Eclipse.

Here is what the portion of the layout looks like that we are interested in. I cropped the full layout to show the relevant part.

[image]

We are now able to break down the following code:

```
View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(1).getParent()).findViewById(2);
```

1. `findViewById(1)` will return the `LinearLayout` (Red Outline) since its id is 1.
2. `getParent()` will return the `RelativeLayout` that is the parent of the `LinearLayout` (Blue Outline).
3. `findViewById(2)` will find the child `View` of the `RelativeLayout` with the given id. Based on the image we see that the `ImageView` (Green Outline) we want has that id.

Based on this it is interesting to note that we could have just used `mapView.findViewById(2)` to get access to the `ImageView` directly and avoid the other calls.

Not sure if that was the case in previous versions but it works when using the current `MapFragment`. If it doesn't work on previous versions then that helps proves the point that this is a bad practice as it can change between releases.

Answer (score 5):

View ids are just positive, non-zero integers.

If you've set the view id in XML using the `@+id/name` syntax, the integer is generated in `R.java` and you need to refer to it as `R.id.name` in code.

If you've set the view id in code using `setId(value)`, you can retrieve a view with that id from a hierarchy with `findViewById(value)` where the id value can well be a hardcoded positive, non-zero integer such as 1 or 2.

Generally when writing code, try to avoid using magic number constants like that.

Comment: right so the magic number.. is just a magic number.. i see this in code sometimes so its' just bad practice that peopel are doing. and they must know what the id 1 is.

Answer (score 0):

they are both same, in first case you are supplying resource identifier which android build in R file by yourself, and in second case you are supplying resource identifier which android has compiled down for you.

no difference whatsoever,

Comment: In the case of the link I supplied findViewById(1)  is the MyLocationButton id. How did the developers know to use that vs. R.id.MyLocationButtonIdIfItExists..

Comment: if you have created an view in runtime and not via XML, then you would probably supplied ID for the same, like setID(1), then you can use findViewById(1) to get back the same. In link you posted, I guess lib woulb have been creating widgets in run time with custom ID.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the view `id` first by using `setId(value)` and then you can retrieve a view using that `id` using `findViewById(value)`

Found this post take a look at it: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/3326331)

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int))  for `setid()`says:

*Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.*