# How to reposition controlMarkerUI for Google Maps API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, location, maps

I've finally managed to get the `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` feature to show up on my map. But I have no clue how to set the constraints for the "recenter" button or the compass that comes with it. They're positioned on the top left and top right by default.

Is there anyway to reposition them or access their constraints?

The activity_maps.xml doesn't show anything.

[image: figure 1]

Comment: may be this could solve your problem. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/change-position-of-google-maps-apis-my-location-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489880/change-position-of-google-maps-apis-my-location-button).